# How to limit number of records in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I want to execute a SELECT query which would return limited number of records in Dynamic SQL for Firebird database server.

similar to the one in SQL of MSSQL

```
 SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table;
```

P.S., i am using interbase 6.0 database with firebird 2.5 odbc driver.

Comment: You mean SELECT TOP(10)* FROM table ?

Comment: oh yes, sorry. I am looking for that kind of select query in dynamic sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with InterBase 6.0 as it doesn't have this feature. [`FIRST n SKIP m`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-first-skip) was added in Firebird 1.0, and [`ROWS m TO n`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows) was added in Firebird 2.0, and SQL standard [`OFFSET`/`FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-offsetfetch) was added in Firebird 3. That you use the Firebird 2.5 ODBC driver(*) is irrelevant: you can only use the features offered by InterBase 6.

InterBase 6 is now +/- 15 years old. You should really consider upgrading, either to Firebird 2.5 or a recent version of InterBase.

<sub>(*): There is no Firebird 2.5 ODBC driver, the [latest version](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/) of the Firebird ODBC driver is 2.0.2</sub>

Comment: yeah i tried both and nothing works. i thought there's something that i am missing, but you are right. Its too old now. Thanks for your response